# Looking for this dystopian book involving a brother and sister that have powers similar to an angel?

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m looking for this book centered around a group of teens that get trapped inside an amusement park. The rest of the world including the parents of the main characters parents have been turned into ravenous monsters. Later on whenever one of them dies they turn into an angel sort of. They have powers that can kill the monsters and when they transform into an angel they are engulfed with fire and can make loud siren noises to kill monsters.....stuff like that. Any help?????

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It would help us help you if you can recall any more details, like when you read it, where you got it...  There's a [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) that has some suggestions that could help; please [edit] in any additional details you think of.